# How to limit a length of a text in android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, maxlength

May I know how to limit the length of a text in `listView` ?

Below is the `listView` from `wechat`

[image]

and this is my `listView`

[image]

> How to limit the length of text so it will display like **this is the
>   work description.Ple...**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the `TextView` to both [singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) and [ellipsize to end](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize), then you should have the desired result.

For example:

```
<TextView
   ...
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:ellipsize="end"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using filter in code (Programmatically in your java class)

```
InputFilter[] FilterArr = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArr[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

or in your xml file as below

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

combined with

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int charactersLimit = 10;
String yourLargeString = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
String yourFinalString = yourLargeString.substring(0, Math.min(yourLargeString.length(), charactersLimit));
yourTextView.setText(yourFinalString + "...");
```

Comment: Although this would work, I think that the OP would prefer to avoid the potential for the line to roll over to the next. Unless the font is monospaced, having a character limit is going to introduce a lot of variability in the height of the view. If for example, the letters just happen to be wider than the average sampling.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Code in java  :

```
tv.setSingleLine();
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

and xml Code :

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code in java

```
       tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_comentdata);
       tv.setMaxLines(3);
       tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML code:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLength="3"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of context about what you're doing?