# How to detect the title is too long in action bar Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have a project, the problem is the title need 2 line but  i want the title just 1 line like this

[image]

Am i have to calculate the character ?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "Ellipsis"

Comment: What is ellipsis? Is it function? @RvdK

Comment: Google for "Android Ellipsis": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393487/how-can-i-show-ellipses-on-my-textview-if-it-is-greater-than-the-1-line

Comment: Can you show me your xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  tv.setSingleLine();
  tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

Source: [How to limit a length of a text in android ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944322/how-to-limit-a-length-of-a-text-in-android-listview)

Answer (score 2):

Add these fields to the textview on your xml layout:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Method 1: Set `singleLine` property to true.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Also, if you want to fit the entire title in one line.

Try setting font size as per screen density:

Create resource folders like:

```
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
```

Create `dimensions.xml` file in each folder with appropriate text size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Set the text in xml or in java file as:

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

Comment: He wants to show the title cut off with 3 dots, not decrease font size.

Comment: @ RvdK In case, he wants to fit the entire title in one line.