# How to limit the number of characters displayed on a ListView Item

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, android-listview, limit

I am making a Notes app where on the front screen, your saved notes appear as a ListView and you can open each one to display their text.
Problem is, right now if I add a note, the ListView displays the full text of the note whereas I would like to show it truncated at the end. For example in the given picture:

[The note displays its full text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpKun.jpg)

I would like the text to be displayed as: *A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d...*

I have tried searching for this and have only found solution for the same problem in TextViews but so far, nothing on ListView Items.

Comment: I believe it's already being answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944322/how-to-limit-a-length-of-a-text-in-android-listview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit a length of a text in android ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944322/how-to-limit-a-length-of-a-text-in-android-listview)

Comment: @RahulTalreja I voted to close this question using your link as a duplicate. SO posted the above comment automatically, I'm not plagiarising. :D

Comment: The answers to this question only talk about limiting text in TextViews when the question mentions ListView. That confused me and since I do not have a textview in my app, I thought of posting a new question.